# How Sprocket's require works?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sprockets, rails-sprockets, i18n-js

I have a file called application.js under app/assets/javascripts

```
// = require libs/jquery-retina
// = require libs/jquery.popupoverlay
// = require libs/messg

// = require site_logic/application
// = require serviceworker-companion

// = require i18n
// = require i18n-rules
// = require lazysizes.min
```

i18n is actually is a gem that I already installed and I don't have any i18n file in the same folder as the application.js file is in and I already saw in the browser that the file was successfully got concatenated to application.js

I wonder how is that possible? because normally the file should be in the same directory.

Answer (score 1):

Sprockets will look through the paths specified in `Rails.application.config.assets.paths` which includes `app/assets`, `lib/assets` and `vendor/assets` it also includes any paths added by Rails engines.

> Assets within an engine work in an identical way to a full
> application. Because the engine class inherits from Rails::Engine, the
> application will know to look up assets in the engine's `app/assets` and
> `lib/assets` directories.

The gems you are using are written as engines, and are mounted when they are required  by `Bundler.require(*Rails.groups)` in `config/application.rb`.

See:

- https://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#asset-organization
- https://guides.rubyonrails.org/engines.html#assets

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I use Rubymine so when I hover over i18n in the application.js file it shows me that the i18n file is located in /home/seifeslimene/.rbenv/versions/2.6.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/i18n-js-3.0.0/app/assets/javascripts/i18n.js
But where in code it's specified that any file can be required from gems?

Comment: Read the guide to engines - if thats not answer enough for you then dig through the rails source code.

Comment: I think you mean sprockets source code in this case.

Comment: Yes, but sprockets really just walks a list of paths to find the file like any kind of loader. Setting up the paths is done by Rails.